# MySQL Help REGEXP Trying to shorten Zipcodes from 9 to 5 digits

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, zip

I have a MySQL table with addresses and some have 5 digit zip codes and some have 9 digit zip codes. A sample record would be like this

```
940 Huguenot Ave Staten Island, NY 10312-4313
```

I need to standardize the database and make all records 5 digit zip codes. My sudo code for something like this was like this

```
If regex [0](5 numeric digits )-[1](4 numeric digits) then update table replace('-[1]','');
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks,

UPDATE ---
zipcode is not an independent field, it is part of the address column, (a sample is above)

Success!
I ended up using a combination of REGEX and SUBSTR using the length of the field -5. Thanks, guys!

Comment: And you can't just take the first five characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support regex replace operations. However, you could first find those records that contain a 9-digit ZIP code:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ZIPcode REGEXP "[[:digit:]]{5}-[[:digit:]]{4}";
```

and then delete the five characters following the dash.

Comment: How would I do it if the zipcode was already part of my address? (Like in my original post)

Comment: This worked on my Address field, I guess I will write a script to fix it for me now! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure why you want to use regexp, but I would just do:

```
update table set zip = substring(zip,1,5);
```

I tried this and it worked beautifully

Comment: How would I do it if the zipcode was part of my address and not a zip column? (Like in my original post)

Comment: I didn't realize that it was part of the column.  I appologize!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL regexes can only find/match text, they cannot modify the data in the tables. Of course, nothing says you can't search for zipcodes by regex, but then do the processing in a script.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE (zipcode REGEX '[[:digit:]]{5}-[[:digit:]]{4}')
```

Comment: How would I do it if the zipcode was already part of my address? (Like in my original post)

Comment: The query will return return any rows where the regex matches, so just do the regex on your address field. I only put `zipcode` as the field because none of us know what the structure of your table is

Comment: I tried this SELECT *
FROM `institutions`
WHERE (`Address` REGEX '[[:digit:]]{5}-[[:digit:]]{4}') and it gave me an error

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEX '[[:digit:]]{5}-[[:digit:]]{4}') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3 . Thanks for your help, @Tim answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used regex in MySQL, but it seems like a simpler regular expression would just check for the '-' character and delete everything after it in the string instead of checking for the right number of digits. Sorry I can't help you with code but hopefully it puts you on the right track.